# Getting Top 10 percent of value for a specific field in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to filter one data field for the top ten percent of values in that field. Something like:

```
SELECT TOP(10)PERCENT IN "TUNGSTEN"
```

However, my database through QGIS does not seem to support SELECT TOP and I am new to these expressions and may be way off.

This artile, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_top.asp, states that :

Note: Not all database systems support SELECT TOP. MySQL uses LIMIT, and Oracle uses ROWNUM.

I'm guessing I may have the wrong code for the database system but I can't make the other options work yet.

Can you give me some direction?

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/373508/88814 or rahter this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384547/exporting-features-when-column-value-between-specific-percentiles

Comment: That looks helpful. I will look into it. Thanks!